# Getting the missing permission

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

How can i get the Missing permission? (api's "missing_perms")

```
elif isinstance(error, commands.MissingPermissions):
            await ctx.message.delete()
            error = discord.Embed(
                title = 'Error',
                description = 'Missing permission!',
                colour = discord.Colour.red()
            )
            error.set_footer(text=version)
            textMsg = await ctx.send(embed=error)
            await textMsg.delete(delay=4)
```

something like "manage_guild"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`MissingPermissions`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.MissingPermissions) object has an attribute `missing_perms`, which is a list of the missing permissions:

```
elif isinstance(error, commands.MissingPermissions):
            await ctx.message.delete()
            embed= discord.Embed(
                title = 'Error',
                description = f'Missing permissions: {error.missing_perms}',
                colour = discord.Colour.red()
            )
            embed.set_footer(text=version)
            textMsg = await ctx.send(embed=embed)
            await textMsg.delete(delay=4)
```